# Unable to build docker image from docker file

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image from my docker file however I get an error
javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java.Can someone help me in this.
I am doing this on my window 10 machine where I have installed docker.
My docker file is as below

```
    FROM java:8
    WORKDIR /abc
    RUN javac HelloWorld.java
    CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
```

Build command

```
    C:\EclipseJavaWorkspace\HelloWorldDocker>docker build -t java-app .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.728kB
    Step 1/4 : FROM java:8
    ---> d23bdf5b1b1b
    Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /abc
    ---> Using cache
 ---> 60d073ad2c81
Step 3/4 : RUN javac HelloWorld.java
 ---> Running in da2d882fc830
javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
The command '/bin/sh -c javac HelloWorld.java' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: The question is misleading. What you mean is "unable to build inside docker image a java file".

The question asked seems to point to not being able to complete a docker build from the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You need to also copy the file inside the container:

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /abc
COPY HelloWorld.java .
RUN javac HelloWorld.java
CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
```

Comment: Ok so I was missing the COPY command in my docker file.I added the COPY HelloWorld.java .  which includes the dot at the end.So it seems after creating the work directory this COPY step is mandatory.This is what I was missing.Thanks a lot for the quick help.

Comment: Also the sequence matters.Earlier I used COPY but, I used COPY prior to the WORKDIR which I read in one of the forums.But the correct sequence should be WORKDIR and then the COPY.

Comment: WORKDIR basically means change directory so yes the order matters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help.
Yes after adding the line COPY HelloWorld.java . it works now.So it means COPY is mandatory after we add the WORKDIR. Below are the lines of code which works perfectly.

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /abc
COPY HelloWorld.java .      // I added this one with a dot at the end
RUN javac HelloWorld.java
CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
```